# Is it better to write each page for every user or to make a generic php file that loads the users info that is logged in

Tags: php

Right now I'm fwriting each users info into a page for each user when they signup and i was wondering if it is a better idea to make a file called profile.php and load all the info from the database into the page

Comment: Yes, it's better to have one page, and load the user information from the session or the database. A site with a lot of users would end up having a lot of duplicate pages on disk!

Comment: A database would be fine and a single `class` for profile is better.

Answer (score 1):

Coding each page for every user? That sounds horrible. You should never do that.
What if your app reaches 1 mil users!!

Just build an authentication system into your app..

Answer (score 1):

You should follow the programming conventions it will help you later to modify your code whenever you will need. Just think if you will hard code the user details in each file and there are say 100's of files then ???

You will end up repeating the same junky code in each file. So its better for you and your application to use proper coding structure. If you will create a single file then later if any change is required you will have to modify it at one place only. Just think over it.
You should follow the saying **(DRY - Don't Repeat Yourself).**